# Partial Effect Plots from spaMM

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a project looking at how private docks are distributed along the coast with respect to a few demographic and landscape variables at the census block group level. Sample data and a .txt with descriptions of the the variable names can be found at (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvVJV9wE-yCEiqQ-qZkfm2DVfXyb2w?e=cXNCTy) and code is below. I am trying to fit a CAR model using the `spaMM` package and have a working model that I can run a LRT on/get confidence intervals for my covariates, but when I try to plot marginal effects using spaMM’s built in `plot_effects()` function I get this error:

> Error in .make_new_corr_lists(object = object, locdata = locdata, which_mats = which_mats,  :
> Found new levels for a 'adjacency' random effect.

I’m at a loss for what this is telling me and am unsure how to resolve this error as I’ve found nothing about this in `spaMM` vignettes or on any other help forums. Additionally, I recognize the `plot_effects()` function makes plots in base R and I was hoping to plot them using ggplot2. I’ve tried the `ggeffects` package and it doesn’t seem to recognize the `spaMM` model object – any suggestions on packages that can handle spaMM objects for plotting in ggplot2? Or will I need to do it by hand?

```
# Load packages/data and make neighbor list/weight matrix #

library(tidyverse)
library(spaMM)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(spdep)
library(ggeffects)

load("Salt1KM.Rda") # This is a .Rda of my data

Salt1KM <- subset(Salt1KM, Block.Group != 252) # This removes one weird outlier

AllFiltersShape <- readOGR(dsn = getwd(), layer =  "All_Filter_BGs") # Load the shapefile of block groups

Neighbors.QN <- poly2nb(AllFiltersShape, queen = TRUE, row.names = AllFiltersShape$BlockID, snap = 1)  # Identify neighbors
Neighbors.QN # Check ouput

QN.adjMat.B <- nb2mat(Neighbors.QN, zero.policy = TRUE, style = "B") #Make binary weights matrix

# Model call and attempt to plot #

QN.B.Dock <- fitme(Dock ~ MHIE + PercentWE + PercentHomeE + Population.Density + Cutoff.Extend.Shore.Estuary.km + (1|Unique.Tract.ID) + adjacency(1|Block.Group), adjMatrix = QN.adjMat.B, data = Salt1KM, family = negbin())
summary(QN.B.Dock)

plot_effects(QN.B.Dock, focal_var = "PercentWE", add = TRUE) # This gives the error in the post

ggpredict(QN.B.Dock, terms = c("PercentWE", "MHIE")) # Attempt at using ggpredict, does not recognize the object at all
```

Comment: As un update - the linked data has polygons that have no neighbors, but this is not causing the issue. I run into the same error with another data set in which every polygon has at least one neighbor.

Comment: A collaborator helped me figure it out. spaMM had an issue because my adjacency factor "Block.Group" was not a sequential list. It was fixed by adding this line to the code before the fitme call:

Salt1KM$Block.Group <- 1:length(Salt1KM$Block.Group)